# gzip not zipping file in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, gzip, gunzip

I am looping into a path and processing/parsing in oracle all files starting with `FF_ARTICLE_*.txt` 
After parsing I am moving the file to archive folder and doing gnzip.

Move command is working and moving the file to archive path, but after moving gzip is not zipping the file.

```
for i in `ls ${INTEGRATION_UTL_FILE_PATH}/FF_ARTICLE_*.txt` 
do
    echo `date '+%m/%d/%Y %T'` Processing file $i ..... >> ${logfile} 
    filename=`basename $i`
    $IPSD/inf2oracle.sh "ecv_ftw_gsm_load.log" "execute oracle_sche.LCI_C_ECV_FTW_STG_LOAD.MAIN_LOAD('${INTEGRATION_UTL_FILE_PATH}','${filename}');" "PROD_USER"
    #****************************
    # Check status of execution *
    #**************************** 
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
         mv $i $HOME/archive/ecv001
         cd $HOME/archive/ecv001
         gzip $HOME/archive/ecv001/$i
    else
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: It would help if you fixed the formatting of your code, and fix any issues reported by running it through shellcheck.

Comment: `for i in \`ls ${INTEGRATION_UTL_FILE_PATH}/FF_ARTICLE_*.txt\`` don't parse using `ls`.  try `for i in ${INTEGRATION_UTL_FILE_PATH}/FF_ARTICLE_*.txt`

Comment: Hi @Shawn. Thanks for reply. Code format is corrected, can you please review it now?

Comment: @DigvijayS Thanks for your reply. I will check that today.

Comment: Or, rather, `for i in "${INTEGRATION_UTL_FILE_PATH}"/FF_ARTICLE_*.txt` so your code doesn't break when the path has spaces. The curly braces are optional and don't really matter; quotes, or the lack of them, really changes behavior. For the same reasons, it should always be `mv "$i" ...`, not `mv $i ...` -- run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and it'll point out all places where quotes are missing (among other common mistakes).

Comment: Also, don't use `something; if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...` -- instead, just use `if something; then ...` -- `if` takes a *command* as the thing to test the exit status of. Instead of testing the command `[` (which you have itself responsible for inspecting the exit status left behind by `inf2oracle`), you could just test the command `inf2oracle` directly.